# Handling response from a POST using jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, rest

I am in a strange situation. I am POSTing on a node server (that performs basic authentication) using the following method:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        accepts: "text/plain",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/somewhere",
        data: JSON.stringify(something),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            window.alert("Received back: '" + data + "'");
        },
        username: theUsername,
        password: "a password"
    }).done(function() {
        alert( "second success" );
    }).fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    }).always(function() {
        alert( "finished" );
    });
```

Now, when the server responds like this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
res.write("1");
res.end();
```

I can see three alert windows popping up:

- Received back '1'
- second success
- finished

However, if I add a character to the string that the server is writing, e.g.

```
res.write("1a");
```

I see two alert windows popping up:

- error
- finished

Why on earth a normal string is actually causing an error in the second case? Any ideas? (By the way, if the server writes down "12" instead of "1a", I have a success.)

Comment: Have you tried adding quotes to the `res.write()` so it escapes it? Like: `res.write("'1a'");`

Comment: You have `dataType: "json",` in your ajax call, and "1a" is not properly formatted json. Neither is "1", but I have a feeling that it might sneak through because it's an integer.. try changing the dataType to html (or commenting it out) and let me know what happens.

Comment: Thank you asifrc. My problem was in data type. For some reason I thought this was for the message going to the server, since accepts indicates text that is expected as an answer. I guess these are all jQuery-newbie mistakes. If you post the answer I will accept. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your content type is text/plain, but your Ajax expects JSON. Change the content-type to be application/json on the response, or change the dataType expected to be "text". Make sure it is valid JSON if you go that route.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait for a day if asifrc posts the same answer as well and I will accept his (posted earlier and with less reputation). Otherwise, I am accepting yours tomorrow. Thanks again.